# Meteor how to use multiple .less files

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use two .less files in a Meteor app.  All files are in a single Meteor app folder.  I have one .less file that defines general UI look-and-feel

In ui.less:

```
.ui-gradient-topdown(@from, @to) {  
   background-color: @from; 

   /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0% 0% 100%, from(@from), to(@to));

   /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to); 

   /* Firefox 3.6+ */
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);

   /* IE 10+ */
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);

   /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
}
```

In myapp.less

```
@import "ui";

html {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
}

body {
  .ui-gradient-topdown(#000, #FFF);
}

#new_message_input {
  background: #F00; 
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

However, in the page that is served up by Meteor, I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui.less.css">

  ... more stuff below ...
```

The myapp.less stylesheet is not imported?

I want to have an app .less file that can @import various mixin .less files.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know why your second less file wouldn't be loaded. But I have seen other discussion on how to import raw less here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152515/external-dependencies-like-bootstrap-in-meteor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because it seems like this question is still current I try to answer it.

In newer versions of meteor (beginning with v0.7.1.1) `.lessimport` got deprecated. The new way is `.import.less`. The way to to it is:

```
// client/mixins.import.less

.opacity(@opacity) {
  opacity: @opacity;
  // IE8 filter
  @opacity-ie: (@opacity * 100);
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity-ie})";
}
```

then @import it in your stylesheet you want to use your mixins in:

```
// client/main.less

@import "mixins.import.less";
// relative to the current file
// if absolute it will be relative to your project root

.some-div {
  .opacity(0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#less):

> If you want to @import a file, give it the extension .lessimport to
>   prevent Meteor from processing it independently.

Comment: Seems to be a known bug which will be fixed soon https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/203

Comment: Nice to see they got it fixed.

Comment: After that do `import "lessfile.lessimport";`

Comment: Correction: "lessimport" was deprecated in favor of "import.less"

Answer (score 3):

What I've come to:

Place all less files in the "client" folder.

Meteor compiles them, therefore there's no need for import statements.

Importing functions works great! Variables break things.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Variables break things" pls.

Comment: It doesn't work here, I can't use a mixin from another file, the files seems to be isolated from each other.
`myapp.less: Less compiler error: .ui-gradient-topdown is undefined`

Comment: This doesn't work in Meteor 1.1. Use instead a "mymixins.import.less" file, and @import it explicitly, e.g. `@import ../relative/path/mymixins.import.less`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment for @EzRaM, and I struggled a bit as Meteor beginner, I hope this helps someone else.

In Meteor 1.6, I wanted to include myOwnMixins.less file to @import another .less file from a node_module, this is what I did:

1) /client/myOwnMixins.less (no need to rename *.import.less)

```
    @import '/node_modules/antd/lib/style/themes/default.less';

    .right {
      float: right;
      height: 100%;
    }

    ... more less code ...
```

2) /imports/ui/layout/MyHeader.js, no need to import /client/myOwnMixins.less files since .less is compiled by meteor and included per default, simple use the className.

```
    <div className="right">Right Aligned</div>
```